# Problem converting an ArrayList to an array

Tags: java, arrays, file, arraylist

I have a code that reads from a file to an ArrayList of type double. Then I convert the ArrayList into an array of type double. 
The following code gives the following error:

```
error: no suitable method found for add(String)
list.add(sCurrentLine)
```

I cannot understand why it doesn't accept the ArrayList's method.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.*;

public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
         List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("testfile.txt"))) 
        {
            String sCurrentLine;
            double DCurrentLine;

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                DCurrentLine = Double.parseDouble(sCurrentLine);
                list.add(sCurrentLine);
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error reading from file");
        } 

        Double[] array = list.toArray(new Double[0]);

        for(Double n : array)
        {
            System.out.println(n);
        }
}
```

Comment: If you read the error message carefully you can see that `sCurrentLine` is a string, not a double. You can't add it to a List<Double>.

Comment: You are adding a `String` to a list that can only contain `Double`. Why should it work? A `String` is **not** a `Double`.

Comment: Oh now I see, however, I cannot use the ```while``` part without the null part

Comment: Thabk you I fixed it! :)